# Is there a way to pass Labels between forms in C# WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms

I was assigned to build a simple Tic Tac Toe game in WinForm. I have the game working but the issue is that all my code is in one class and my professor is asking us to separate our code into 3 classes.

- main.cs: Basically runs the program and creates a frame class
- frame.cs: Contains everything regarding the design and look of the form. Also deals with the basic mechanics of the game (displaying alternating X's and O's, declaring a draw after 9 turns, and clearing the board )
- algorithm.cs: Should only contain a function that determines the winner of Tic Tac Toe. Detects when 3 X's or O's are lined up either vertically, horizontally, or diagonally.

Right now I have my code working but it is all in frame.cs. I need to take this function, checkForWinner() and place it in algorithm.cs. The only issue I am having is that the other class does not see my labels. I need to find a way to pass all 9 labels into the algorithm class for the code to compile. I am familiar with passing simple data types through classes but I have never tried it with labels, let alone 9 of them. I'm guessing I need to make some getters and setters but I am unfamiliar with how that would work with Labels.
Here is my algorithm class:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class TicTacToeAlgorithm : Form
{
    public TicTacToeAlgorithm()
    {

    }

    private void checkForWinner()
    {
        bool isThereAWinner = false;
        //Horizontal checks
        if ((A1.Text == A2.Text) && (A2.Text == A3.Text) && (!A1.Enabled)) { isThereAWinner = true; }
        else if ((B1.Text == B2.Text) && (B2.Text == B3.Text) && (!B1.Enabled)) { isThereAWinner = true; }
        else if ((C1.Text == C2.Text) && (C2.Text == C3.Text) && (!C1.Enabled)) { isThereAWinner = true; }
        //Vertical checks
        if ((A1.Text == B1.Text) && (B1.Text == C1.Text) && (!A1.Enabled)) { isThereAWinner = true; }
        else if ((A2.Text == B2.Text) && (B2.Text == C2.Text) && (!A2.Enabled)) { isThereAWinner = true; }
        else if ((A3.Text == B3.Text) && (B3.Text == C3.Text) && (!A3.Enabled)) { isThereAWinner = true; }
        // Diagonal
        if ((A1.Text == B2.Text) && (B2.Text == C3.Text) && (!A1.Enabled)) { isThereAWinner = true; }
        else if ((C1.Text == B2.Text) && (B2.Text == A3.Text) && (!C1.Enabled)) { isThereAWinner = true; }

        if (isThereAWinner)
        {
            winnerText = "Winner: " + currentPlayer;
            winner.Text = winnerText;

        }
    }
}
```

I know I am still pretty new to stack overflow but any help is greatly appreciated and yes I know I should have used buttons instead of labels but my professor wanted us to detect mouse movement with his assignment for some reason. I already have main working because it does not need to pass any variables through.

Comment: You could pass across the form instance itself. This will require making the control references `public` which you can do from the Properties panel

Comment: Could also expose the labels via public properties. And if you don't need the whole label, just expose whatever you need.

Comment: Storing program state in controls and strings is a very traditional newbie mistake.  You will have to do this all over again when you decide to use, say, pictureboxes instead of labels.  Separate the data from the view, an Piece[3,3] array is the proper and efficient way to model the game board.  Painting it is an implementation detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only really need to 'get' the values in labels, and don't ever need to write back to them, you could write a `public` method in your `frame.cs` that returns the 'values' (as opposed to the entire label) of labels.

```
public List<string> GetLabelText()
{
    var labels = new List<string>();
    labels.Add(A1.Text);
    labels.Add(A2.Text);
    // Add all the others
    return labels;
}
```

If you want to be more thorough, you could return a dictionary that has the label name and value.

```
public Dictionary<string, string> GetLabelText()
{
    var labels = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    labels.Add(A1.Name, A1.Text);
    labels.Add(A2.Name, A2.Text);
    // Add all the others
    return labels;
}
```

Then to set the `winner` you'd need to do pretty much the same process in reverse. In your `frame.cs`, write another function to set the value to that label.

Comment: So I created the public function in my frame class. But if I want to access this list from my Algorithm I would have to call the function? Because I tried calling the function but it is still showing up as undefined. Maybe I'm not including the algorithm class, is there anything I need to make sure I have to link these two classes.

Comment: Yeah, that's the idea.

Comment: Alright so I made sure my algorithm is only running after each user input but  it is still not recognizing he GetLabelText function along with every Label. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by 'not recognizing'?

Comment: It still says that GetLabelText does not exist in the current context and so does all of my labels.

Comment: You should probably first try to understand the concept of classes. We shouldn't really talk in file names (such as `frame.cs`) but in classes. Your `frame.cs` has a class, so to tall a method of that class you need an instance of it (unless that class is `static`). So to call the method you do `instanceofclass.GetLabelText()`. Please do further reading on classes and objects.

Comment: Ah, yes that seemed to have worked thank you so much Sach. i'm really learning a lot thanks to you.